# A view is presented on the click of a button. As soon as i click on the button, the view moves at the left

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, presentviewcontroller

[image]In my project, i have a button which presents a viewController (transitionStyle is coverVertical and modalPresentationStyle is FormSheet). I want the view should be presented at the centre but on the click of the button, the view opens at the left and then when the keyboard is put down it moves at the centre. Can anyone tell me why? I have used viewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;

Check out my presentingViewController code which i have put in the click of the button.

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 650);
        viewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center; viewController.delegate = self;

Comment: This is the code for presenting the view when clicked on the button

Comment: Please edit your question and insert your code, and use tools to make your question readable. If your question is not clear, it will be downvoted.

Comment: @AncAinu : Check my edited question. I have put the code.

Comment: @user3202087 next time just indent your code by 4 space, stackoverflow will color it for you, no need for a screenshot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see if it works

```
 viewcontroller.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.centre.x-540)/2, (self.view.centre.y-650)/2, 540, 650);
```

Comment: no. Thats not working. Its giving me incompatible type error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question. Instead of using

```
[self presentViewController:vcRevaluateInventory animated:YES completion:nil];
```

for presenting the view, just use

```
[self presentViewController:vcRevaluateInventory animated:YES completion:^{
        vcRevaluateInventory.view.superview.bounds = vcRevaluateInventory.view.frame;
    }];
```